# Probability help! Am I even doing this right?

Tags: probability, statistics

I am really bad with probability, so I just want some explanations and help with this problem (and probably many more to come!) and I also want to know if I am on the right track. Thank you!

**Lyme disease is a disease carried by ticks, which can be transmitted
to humans by tick bites. Suppose the probability of contracting the disease is 1/100
for each tick bite.**

**a. What is the probability that you will not get the disease when bitten once?**

I know that the probability of NOT getting the disease is 99/100, so if it is one time you get bitten, then the probability that you will not get the disease when bitten once IS 99/100, right? Since it is only one time.

**b. What is the probability that you will not get the disease from your first tick bite,
and will the it from your second tick bite?**

I did (probability of NOT getting the disease) x (probability of getting the disease). So I got (99/100) x (1/100) = 99/10000 as the answer. Am I correct? I think the events are independent from each other.

Comment: If they are independent, then you are on the right track.

Comment: The two answers are correct. You're not correct about being really bad with probability. Perhaps you're a little bad (although there is nothing here to support that either), but you're most likely not really bad.